# What SBT build setting can I use with the Play! 2 framework that will include specific resources from the source tree on the class path

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt

I would like to add a setting to the build that will copy specific files from a location within src tree so that they are available on the class path in dev and production mode. I don’t want to put them in the `public` folder because I don’t want them to be available to download. And I don’t want to put them in the `conf` folder because I want to keep that clean for configuration files.

For example:

```
app
  -- views
     -- website
        -- view.scala.html
        -- header-module.widget
        -- footer-module.widget
```

When the application is compiled I would like the class path to include both the `*.widget` files under `classpath:views/website/` and not the `view.scala.html` because that is processed separately.

I would like to do this by adding an sbt setting where I can provide a filter, I’ve already tried this and some variations, but have not had it working so far:

```
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
  // Add your own project settings here
  unmanagedResources in Compile <++= (sourceDirectory in Compile) map {
    base: File => ( base / "views" ** "*. widget ").get
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following inside `.settings()` should work:

```
// Add app folder as resource directory so that widget files are in the classpath
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile <+= baseDirectory( _ / "app" ),
// but filter out java and html files that would then also be copied to the classpath
excludeFilter in Compile in unmanagedResources := "*.java" || "*.html"
```

I have s.th. like this in our Build.scala to have mybatis xml files in the classpath and it's working for us.

Comment: Perfect for us too. Note : only the content of the directory is copied and not the directory itself. This is true for the '/conf' folder for example so configuration files like 'application.conf' are actually in the root of the jar file and not in 'conf/'. This is important when trying to load files using Play.application().resourceAsStream("myfile.x")